# [Ruby]IO.Read not reading the whole file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file, io

I want to download a zip file containing some images via a rails method. The problem is that when I try to read thoses files, I'm not getting the entire file. Of course, that's pretty much annoying to display the image.

Here is my code :

```
  def download_zip(image_list)
    if !image_list.blank?
      file_name = "pictures.zip"
      t = Tempfile.new("lolbite11")
      Zip::OutputStream.open(t.path) do |z|
        image_list.each do |img|
          title = img.name
          title += ".jpg" unless title.end_with?(".jpg")
          z.put_next_entry(title)
          z.print IO.read(Rails.root.join('public', img.path)) <- Here is the problem ?
        end
      end
      send_file t.path, :type => 'application/zip',
                :disposition => 'attachment',
                :filename => file_name
      t.close
    end
  end
```

After I've download the zip and extract it. I open my images with a text editor and sadly see that I've not the whole image... I tried to output the 'IO.read' and it's only displaying what is in my final file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found an other way to solve my problem with File.copy_stream().

But if someone knows why this doesn't work, feel free to explain to me.